# Bootstrap 5 navbar nav-link items not working

Tags: navbar, bootstrap-5

I'm having trouble adding a bootstrap navbar to my site, links will only work if I place them inside of a dropdown... if I add a regular nav-item > nav-link to the navbar it appears as text on the live site. I've read a ton of docs and threads and I cannot figure this out... I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, or what to look for at this point and I would really appreciate any feedback!

Here is my html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
<div class="container-fluid"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO</a> <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
<ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#overview">Overview </a></li>
<li class="nav-item dropdown"><a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Next Steps</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#next_steps">Personalized</a></li>
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#general_next_steps">General</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="nav-item dropdown"><a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Resources </a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#resources">Tutorials</a></li>
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
<form class="d-flex"><button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Log In</button></form></div>
</div>
</nav>
```

The only CSS I've changed from the Bootstrap file is:

```
.navbar {
  top: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  z-index: 99 !important;
}

.container-fluid { max-width: 1440px !important; }
```

Comment: Markup looks fine to me. How are you loading bootstrap script and css?

Comment: I'm adding to a site built on a hosting platform so I have the bootstrap stylesheet and script added to a field for google meta verify code. That's the closest to adding directly to the head tag I could find... it's worked for my own stylesheet so far, but maybe that's the issue?